# How do you set a priority on auto-layouts default spacing metric in a visual format?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, uikit, autolayout, appkit

Auto-layout uses the `-` symbol to indicate that a constraint should use the default spacing. Is there a way to set the priority on that spacing without having to explicitly set a metric value?

For example, the following visual format will create a leading constraint between `myView` and its superview equal to the default Cocoa/CocoaTouch value. But that constraint has a priority of `required`.

`@"H:|-[myView]"`

The following will create a leading constraint with a lower priority but an explicit metric value must be specified:

`@"H:|-(10@750)-[myView]"`

I want to be able to give the leading constraint a priority, but not an explicit metric. The reasoning being that 1) I don't want to have to guess what Apple's value is and 2) To future proof if Apple changes that value.

Ideally, I'd like something like that following:

`@"H:|-(@750)-[myView]"` or `@"H:|-(-@750)-[myView]"`

But neither are accepted grammar. Is there a secret format string that would achieve this?

*(I don't think there's a difference between iOS and MacOS for something like this, but if there is, I'm targetting MacOS.)*

Comment: Excellent question. Facing the exact same problem right now. Seems you didn't find the answer yet, did you ?

Comment: Nope, sorry. Didn't come across anything in the documentation, release notes or WWDC videos. If there's a way, I've either looked right over it or it's undocumented.

Comment: Did someone already find a solution to this one?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set priority for default spacing in visual format constraints. You can only do it when you create a constraint explicitly.

```
let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .leadingMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
constraint.priority = 750
```

You can get the default spacing by specifiying attributes as **leadingMargin** and **trailingMargin** instead of using just **leading** and **trailing**.